# How to create .VCD file or Simulation activity file of verilog code?

Tags: verilog, xilinx

I have Verilog's code. It is simulated correctly and synthesize too. I wanted to write.VCD(value change dumped) file.
I got from internet few command to generate VCD file as given below:

```
initial begin
$dumpfile ("invchn26.vcd"); // Change filename as appropriate. 
$dumpvars(1, t.uut); 
end
```

But have few amount of confusion:
1. The above lines will be written on the testbench. Am I right?
2. I have below files:
testbench: stimulus.v ,
 the main file named F_E. it is instance by name call in stimulus file. like written as F_E call (a,b,CLK,x,y);
I wrote below lines in stimulus (testbench file) :

```
 initial begin
    $dumpfile ("crt.vcd"); // Change filename as appropriate. 
    $dumpvars(1, stimulus.call); 
    end
```

But its giving error. 
How DO I create .VCD file with verilog and xilinx. 
Please suggest hints.

Comment: The iSim simulator can write VCD files. There is the `-vcdfile <vcd_file>` command line option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I show an example on linux, the steps with new names to avoid mixing the names and modules with your filenames.)

If you have a file, let´s say, "counter.v", then you would write a testbench file, say "counter_tb.v" (for the sake of clarity, it is better to name the testbench file "something_tb.v" for the file "something.v"). In the testbench-file, you give the vcd file name, as you mentioned:

```
$dumpfile("counter.vcd")
$dumpvars(0, counter_tb)   <= Name of the testbench module
```

In the testbench file, there has also to be the include command for the module under test:

```
`include "counter.v"
 module
     counter_tb();
 ...
 ...
```

Then you would compile (on Linux):

```
iverilog -o counter counter_tb.v
```

Then this can be processed with the command

```
vvp counter
```

which produces the output-file "counter.vcd" which can be inspected by the command

```
gtkwave counter.vcd
```

If all the steps above where correct, there should be no complain

Comment: I am using window operating system. What if we write $dumpvars(1, counter_tb)?

Comment: The argument "1" in the $dumpvars command says that only the listed variables and variables of listed modules will be dumped. "0" that all variables within the modules from the list will be dumped